# Linux DHCP for multiple subnet

Tags: linux, dhcp

```
vlan10---->firewall----->linux dhcp server
vlan20---------↑
```

I have two vlan(vlan10 and vlan20), and I would like to use Linux DHCP server to centralize IP address designation.

In fortigate firewall I use dhcp relay for client get dhcp ip.

In linux dhcp server I use [host] section to limit client get static ip 
and allow known hosts to get dynamic ip.

```
########## config start #########

subnet 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.10.255;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.8.248,192.168.8.246;
option routers 192.168.10.1;
allow unknown-clients;
range 192.168.10.11 192.168.10.210;
}

subnet 192.168.20.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.20.255;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.8.248,192.168.8.246;
option routers 192.168.20.1;
deny unknown-clients;
range 192.168.20.11 192.168.20.210;
}

host host1  {
       hardware ethernet 11:11:11:11:11:11;
       fixed-address 192.168.10.20;
}

host host2  {
       hardware ethernet 22:22:22:22:22:22;
       fixed-address 192.168.10.21;
}

host host3  {
       hardware ethernet 33:33:33:33:33:33;
       fixed-address 192.168.20.20;
}

host host4 {
       hardware ethernet 44:44:44:44:44:44;
}

########## config end #########
```

in this configuration, all clients can get ip from vlan10 or vlan20, but I want host4 can get dynamic ip in vlan20 only.

When host4 connect to vlan10, host4 cannot get any ip address from dhcp server.

How can I modify the configuration?

Comment: I just try, you can add the host line in the subnet part. Maybe will it work

Comment: thanks your reply, i try it before...

i add "host host4" into subnet192.168.20.0, host4 can get 192.168.20.0/24 ip address....that's right....

but when host4 connect to vlan10 switch port, it get 192.168.10.0/24 ip....
i dont want host4 get any ip when it connect to vlan10...

Answer (score 0):

**While I can't currently test this out**, and it may need some tweaking for syntax, you may be able to use 'group' definitions and list all clients in groups for vlan10 and vlan20, but in the vlan10 file, you tell host4 to 'deny booting;' which should do it.

I can't test this myself at the moment, but it may be worth a try?

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-dhcp-configuring-server.html#group
https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/dhcpd.conf.5.html for deny booting

You may also want to see if the 'includes' directive will work, so you could do something like:

dhcp.conf:

```
option domain-name-servers 192.168.8.248,192.168.8.246;
include "/etc/dhcp/vlan10.txt"
include "/etc/dhcp/vlan20.txt"
```

vlan10.txt

```
group {
subnet 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 { 
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.10.255;
option routers 192.168.10.1;
allow unknown-clients;
range 192.168.10.11 192.168.10.210;
include "/etc/dhcp/vlan10.hosts.txt"
include "/etc/dhcp/vlan10.deny.hosts.txt"
 }
}
```

vlan20.txt

```
group {
subnet 192.168.20.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.20.255;
option routers 192.168.20.1;
deny unknown-clients;
range 192.168.20.11 192.168.20.210;
include "/etc/dhcp/vlan10.hosts.txt"
include "/etc/dhcp/vlan20.hosts.txt"
 }
}
```

vlan10.hosts.txt

```
host host1 { hardware ethernet 11:11:11:11:11:11; fixed-address 192.168.10.20; }

host host2 { hardware ethernet 22:22:22:22:22:22; fixed-address 192.168.10.21; }

host host3 { hardware ethernet 33:33:33:33:33:33; fixed-address 192.168.20.20; }
```

vlan10.deny.hosts.txt

```
host host4 { hardware ethernet 44:44:44:44:44:44; deny booting; }
```

vlan20.hosts.txt

```
host host4 { hardware ethernet 44:44:44:44:44:44; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe creating a class matching your host4 and adding a line with "deny members of 'yourClass';" in your subnet configuration can help

an example :

```
class "raspberry"
{
    # match mac starting with b8:27:eb
    match if substring(hardware, 1, 3) = b8:27:eb;
}

subnet 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.254.0 {
    option routers 192.168.10.254;
    pool {
        range 192.168.10.11 192.168.10.210;
        deny members of "raspberry";
    }
}
```